# With Zxing retiring for iOS, which barcode-scanner to switch to?

Tags: ios, zxing, barcode-scanner, zbar

I have implemented ZXing to my iOS-app, however I am questioning it's maintainability as not long ago it was announced that ZXing to iOS is retiring:

[Retiring C++, Objective C code](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/zxing/L2oGZllqwXI)

I've also read that there might be compatibility issues with the newer phones iPhone 5S..

Also running Xcode's static code analysis on the Zxing-library reveals memory errors, I'm not sure if these errors are false positive or not, but they make me doubt Zxing even more. Further, the performance of Zxing compared to other barcode scanners feels subpar.

So my question is, what is the best alternative? I hear a lot of good stuff about Zbar, however I'm not sure how updated it is either.

Comment: I've been using [ZXingObjC](https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC). Works great.

Comment: Have you tested Xcode's analyze for ZXingOjbC?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

iOS 7 SDK now includes a QR code reader, `AVCaptureMetaDataOutput`. You can read about it at
[i​OS 7 NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/ios7/).

Comment: Right, Should have added that we target 5.0 at the moment. I will consider changing the target!

Comment: if you check the stats you'll see that almost nobody is on 5.0. Given all the cool stuff now on iOS6 and iOS7, not to mention the complete design overhaul, unless you have a crazy budget, it makes sense to shoot for iOS7

Comment: I agree with you, however need to convince some people.. I'm thinking of keeping the target 5.0, but only allow devices that have iOS7 and later to use the scanning functionality.

Comment: I've been trying out AVCaptureMetaDataOutput now, and the accuracy is just awful..

Comment: The built in iOS reader doesn't work for ByteMode QRs. Check out the still maintained ZXingObj: https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC

Answer (score 4):

The latest and updated zXing for iOS 6 and later is available here... https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC
It's not going to retire... :)

Comment: Is there an easy way to get an equivalent of https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/barcodes-scanner/id417257150?mt=8 based on ZXingObjC? I'm not an iOS developer, I was just hoping for something I could launch from a browser which would work as described here: https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Scanning-From-Web-Pages

Answer (score 2):

try zbar sdk, it's compatible with ios 7 sdk

http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/index.html

or

http://www.scandit.com/barcode-scanner-sdk/features/platforms/

Comment: Scandit looked really nice, however I can't use it as it isn't open source

Answer (score 2):

You can try [PDF417.mobi](http://pdf417.mobi). It is commercial but can be used for free for educational and non-commercial purposes.

PS. I'm working for the team that developed PDF417.mobi SDK.

Comment: Did you check the documentation from this link? https://github.com/PDF417/pdf417-ios/blob/master/README.md

Comment: yes, but i need an example for the code after importing its project to my code

Comment: @Mutawe there is a sample project https://github.com/PDF417/pdf417-ios/tree/master/pdf417-sample