# Barcode scanner SDK for iOS 7 and 8 (Free version)

Tags: ios, iphone, zxing, barcode-scanner, zbar-sdk

I'm trying to implement a barcode scanner for our iOS app and we are targetting iOS 7 and iOS 8.We have tried almost all the SDKs that are available.
Among which I found ZBar and ZXing SDKs which are open source SDKs.

(Tried the native barcode available for iOS but it does not solve most of our requirements and the accuracy is awful).

WRT ZXing SDK, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20144071/with-zxing-retiring-for-ios-which-barcode-scanner-to-switch-to). And even I don't think that it is compatible with higher versions of iOS 7 and 8.

As of now ZBar SDK works fine but on [github](https://github.com/markdarling/ZBar-SDK-iOS) the code seems to be updated long back.
I want to know whether to proceed with this or not?

Need your suggestions.....

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: r u get any deprecated methods

Comment: AVFoundation also provides the QR scanner and Bar code scanner, make sure if that doesn't meet your requirement to go for 3rd party libraries

Answer (score 3):

Hope this would help. As we are using ZBar SDK which is working perfactly fine with our project for scanning Bar Codes & QR Codes even  on latest iOS version i would recommend using it.

Also please use the latest version of ZBar SDK with 64-bit architecture support:

ZBar SDK 64 Bit for iPhone 6 and iOS 8 download
https://markobl.com/2015/03/27/zbar-sdk-64-bit-for-iphone-6-and-ios-8-download/

[Download ZBar SDK](https://owncloud.markobl.com/index.php/s/5VQP7k3CsVCCNQV/download) with 64 Bit and iPhone 6 support (3 MB)

Comment: it's working for me.